# Significance of parentheses before returning a super constructor in Java?

Tags: java, superclass, super

I'm looking at how to do deep copies using the clone method() (not my idea, but my professors) and I Keep seeing code where they put the class type inside Parentheses before using the super constructor.

```
@Override
protected Rectangle clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return (Rectangle) super.clone();
}
```

What is the point of **(Rectangle)** used before super.clone();

I've also seen the use of this when using :

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if ((Rectangle)(e.getSource())).getAngle1() == 60){
          System.out.println("Angle is 60");
        } 
  }
```

Is this use of **(Rectangle)** doing the same thing?

I'm trying to find documentation for this, but I'm having trouble googling it. Could someone explain this or point me to the right location? Thank you!

edit: This has been marked as a duplicate, I just read the "duplicate posts", which go on to explain typecasting. 
**Could someone explain how you can typecast an ActionEvent into another class? How does the inheritance around that even work? From my perspective, it does not seem like ActionListner inherits anything from Rectangle, so how is it being typecast? Same thing for typecasting a super constructor. If I'm using a super constructor would it not already be of type Rectangle?**

Answers: You need to type cast a cloned super constructor because the clone method returns an object and not a Rectangle!

Comment: Search for "casting in Java".

Comment: Another dupe: [Parentheses around data type?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9344271)

Comment: @antonH Ok, so I know what casting is, but I didn't know that you could cast methods? as well as constructors?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out here that the reason you have to cast the result of calling clone is that clone returns an Object.  And if that seems weird to you, that's the least of its problems as the clone method is known to be "broken" (cf Joshua Bloch in Effective Java).

Comment: @C S Thank you! that's what I was wondering, and the other "duplicate posts" did not address this!

Comment: @cicero866 You're not casting the method, you're casting the object that the method is returning. Whether you're casting something directly, or when it's returned from a mthod, makes no difference.

Comment: You can't cast constructors. Constructors don't return a value. You can cast a `new` expression but that's likely to be the result of a bad decision.